# Comparison between wave equation theory and transfer function theory

Tags: waves, wavefunction, acoustics, signal-processing

I deal with analysis of acoustic signals in solids. And after some literature research in physics and mathematic, I have a question about the followings two theories:

- Wave equation theory: Imagine I have a simple plane wave $Ae^{j\omega (t-x/c)}$ propagating from medium 1 through medium 2 to medium 3. According to the theory, the transmitted acoustic wave in medium 3 is dependent on the incident wave frequency $\omega$ and characteristic acoustic impedances of these 3 media. Using the boundary condition, i.e. there is no discontinuity in the wave propagation, the transmitted wave could be theoretically described.
- Transfer function theory: The same example as above. The transmitted acoustic wave could be described as a multiplication of the transfer function of media 1 to 3 in the frequency domain, assuming that the system is linear time-invariant.

So basically one can use these two theories to verify each other. Is that correctly understood? Have anyone tried that?

Comment: What do you mean by "has anyone tried yet"? Anyhow you have a transfer function, including impedances, admittances, scattering coefficients, and some such, for any mathematically *reasonable* linear time invariant system, such as wave equations, RLC circuits, acoustics, etc.

Comment: You usually *derive* the transfer matrix formalism from the plane-wave version (for, e.g., optical systems, quantum mechanical systems, etc.). They are equivalent.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.